$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} + \frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{2}= x^2,$ three successive triangular numbers whose sum is square
$\Large\frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} + \frac{(n+2)(n+3)}{2}= \quad x^2$
$\Large= \frac{3n^2 + 9n + 8}{2}= \quad x^2$
$=3n^2 + 9n + (8 - 2x^2) = 0$
$\text{Discriminant must be a perfect square, so}$
$\large 81 - 4 \cdot 3 \cdot (8 - 2x^2) = y^2$
$\large\Rightarrow 24x^2 - 15 = y^2$
$\large\Rightarrow 24x^2 - y^2 = 15$
$\Large \Rightarrow \left(\frac{\sqrt24x}{\sqrt15}\right)^2 - \frac{1}{15} y^2 = 1$
$\large\text{Let } X = \frac{\sqrt24x}{\sqrt15}$
$\large X^2 - \frac{1}{15} y^2 = 1$


$\large X = 4, \, y = 15$


$\large \therefore x = \sqrt{10}$


$\large 3n^2 - 9n + (8 - 20) = 0$


$\large n = 1
$
Which means that the numbers are $1,3,6,$ but $10$ is not a perfect square.I can't see what I even did wrong.
Edit; Everyone that's not what I meant I meant to include the square roots argh I'm so sorry.
Edit2; If anyone's still seeing this I basically have to try even larger numbers, (4,15) yields $\sqrt10$ but how far do I even go like this? Commentators have suggested (19,93) but wow that is large. My last question is that do I have to run through quintillion values like this and run computer programs for a single sum? Wow. If anyone has another way of solving this please suggest this is litteraly becoming impossible without guessing.The other post including this had $0$ answers I understood.

What do you mean by successive triangular numbers ? Will their common difference be same or different?

If their common difference is same then $2,3,4$ can be an example

@Mathematics, Successive triangular numbers are triangular numbers of successive numbers.

@Mathematics, different triangular numbers are sums of 1+2+...

The problem is that $x = \sqrt{10}$ isn't an integer. It is still true that $1 + 3 + 6 = x^2$ here.

You found $X$ is a whole number, but you need $x$ is a whole number.  They are never both whole numbers (except 0).

@eyeballfrog argh finally a real answer. I checked so many things multiple times before posting here and I completely forgot that.

@Empy2, never both whole numbers, really?

Their ratio is $\sqrt{24/15}$ which is irrational.

@Empy2 ahh yea that's true. What am I even supposed to do now....

@xoco please check my edit

Why must your discriminant be a perfect square?

For a solution-verification question to be on topic you must specify precisely which step in the proof you question, and why so. This site is not meant to be used as a proof checking machine.

@BillDubuque, I don't question any step of the proof. It flowed in a correct way all through. I can't make up a flaw, can I? I was wondering why it wasn't working. Which was just a slight mistake I overlooked, I had to find a whole number value of x. It's not even a PROOF at all. You're acting like you're all smart and downvoting me when I asked a question after hours of research.

@xoco My comment merely informs you of site policy. It has nothing to do with downvoting.

For this new answer I owe much credit to @CalvinLin for their precious contribution in the comments.
Consider the equation $y^2 - 24x^2 = - 15, \tag{1}$ which has the particular solution $(x,y)=(1,3)$. As I stated in the previous answer, you can check that this solution leads to $3n^2 + 9n + 6 = 0 \implies n=-1 \lor n=-2$ which are not natural numbers. Therefore, we must find another couple $(x, y)$ which works without a computer.
Now consider the Pell's equation $y^2 - 24x^2 = 1; \tag{2}$
also, let $(a,b)$ be a solution of $(1)$ and $(c,d)$ be a solution of $(2)$. Hence, $b^2 - 24a^2 = - 15$ and $d^2 - 24c^2 = 1$. I claim that $(bc+ad, bd+24ac)$ is another solution of $(1)$, which means $(bd+24ac)^2 - 24(bc+ad)^2 = - 15$.
For the proof, it is enough to observe that $(bd+24ac)^2 - 24(bc+ad)^2 = (b^2 - 24a^2)(d^2 - 24c^2) = (-15)(1)=-15.$
Now, observe that one solution of $(2)$ is $(x,y)=(1,5)$. Therefore, choose $(a,b)=(1,3)$ and $(c,d)=(1,5)$. By the previous claim $(x,y)=(3\cdot 1+1 \cdot 5, 3\cdot 5 + 24 \cdot 1 \cdot \ 1) = (8, 39)$ solves $(1).$ You can check that this value of $x$ gives $3n^2+9n-120= 0 \implies n^2+3n-40= 0 \implies (n-5)(n+8)=0$ which has the valid solution $n=5.$ It also satisfies $\frac{5 \cdot 6}{2} + \frac{6 \cdot 7}{2} + \frac{7 \cdot 8}{2} = 15 + 21 + 28 = 64 = 8^2. \square$
EDIT:
We define the operation $*$ such that $(a, b)*(c,d)=(bc+ad, bd+24ac)$. The previous claim tells us that by iteration we obtain a sequence of solutions $(x_n,y_n)$ to $y^2 - 24x^2 = - 15$ letting $$\\(x_0, y_0)=(1,3) \\(x_1, y_1)=(x_0,y_0)*(1,5) \\ (x_2, y_2)=(x_1,y_1)*(1,5) \\\vdots$$
Now observe that the equation $3n^2+9n+(8-2x^2)=0$ together with $y^2 - 24x^2 = - 15$ turns into $n^2+3n+\left(\frac{-y^2}{36}+\frac{9}{4}\right)=0 \implies n=\frac{-9\pm y}{6}$. Therefore, apparently you need to check for every solution $(x,y)$ if $n \in \mathbb{Q}$ or  $n \in \mathbb{N}$. However, I will prove by induction that in the previous sequence $y_k$ is always an odd multiple of $3$.
BASE CASE: $y_0 = 3$ by definition and $y_1 = 39$ by previous calculation.
INDUCTIVE STEP: suppose $y_k$ is an odd multiple of $3$. Then, by definition, $(x_{k+1}, y_{k+1})= (x_k, y_k)*(1,5) = (y_k+5x_k,5y_k+24x_k)$. Now let us focus on $y_{k+1}$. Recall that $y_k$ is an odd multiple of $3$, so let $y_k=3(2m+1)$, for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $y_{k+1} = 5y_k+24x_k = 5 \cdot 3(2m+1) + 24x_k = 3 (10m + 5 + 8x_k) = 3 [1+2(2+5m+4x_k)]$ which is an odd multiple of $3$. Therefore, for every $y$ in this sequence you actually get $n=\frac{-9\pm y}{6} \in \mathbb{Z} $ and in particular $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for $k\geq 1$ without needing to check (unless you want to know its value).
I should really conclude by saying that you can check by hand that $x=8$ is the smallest value that works, i. e. $3n^2 + 9n + (8-2x^2)= 0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{N}$ for $x \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\} $.

1/ $(x, y) = (1, 3)$ doesn't satisfy $n \neq -1, -2$ doesn't imply "therefore we must find another couple $(x,y)$ which works without a computer". $\quad$ 3/ To classify all solutions, it requires some exhaustive search. Checking $x$ from 1 to 8 is enough (from the starting value $(y, x)$ to the next $(y, x) * (1, 5)$) , with the only other solution $x = 2$. $\quad$ 3/ Bear in mind that you've only found solutions where the discriminant is a perfect square, and still need to check that $n$ is an integer.

@CalvinLin I don't understand your first point. The OP is looking for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and the particular solution $(x, y) = (1,3)$ leads to the two solutions $n=-1,n=-2$

@CalvinLin and I also don't get your last point: I checked that the quadratic equation $3n^2+9n-120$, obtained for $x=8$, gives $n=5$; if the discriminant is not a perfect square the solutions are irrational. Could you please be more specific?

1/ I agree with you about that conclusion. I'm saying that  conclusion doesn't imply that we must find another without a computer.  $\quad$ 3/ Discriminant is a perfect square only implies that the solutions are rational. The solutions are $ n = ( - 9 \pm y ) / 6$, so why must this be an integer?

@CalvinLin well, I said "without a computer" because the OP was looking for an efficient method to find the solution without checking by hand or using a computer. As regards the discriminant, I meant that the  discriminant being a perfect square is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition to find an integer $n$ as a solution. Then it is easy to check that the value $x=8$ you found in your comments actually gives $n \in \mathbb{N}$

1/ Noted. $\quad$ 3/ I was hoping you would show that $y$ is an odd multiple of 3, and hence $ n = (  - 9 \pm y ) / 6$ is always an integer, thus filling the gap of "necessary (but not sufficient) condition to find an integer  $n$".

@CalvinLin please check my edit. Thanks for challenging me :)

Looks good. One can also argue directly from $24 x^2 - y^2 = 15$ that clearly $y$ is a multiple of 3, and is odd.

(I'm talking about the part after EDIT)How do you know that the operation  $(a, b)*(c,d)=(bc+ad, bd+24ac)$ is correct? Also, by the previous claim, don't we obtain solutions to $y^2 - 24x^2 = 1$ and not  $y^2 - 24x^2 = -15$?

I'm not sure what you mean by "correct". It's a definition based on the fact that applying the operation $*$ to a solution $(x, y)=(a , b)$ of $(1)$ and a solution $(x, y)=(c , d)$ of $(2)$ you get another solution of $(1)$, since $(x,y)=(bc+ad, bd+24ac) \implies y^2-24x^2 = -15$ as I showed. Also note that not all the solutions of $(1)$ are obtained by my sequence, as I discussed in the comments with Calvin Lin: for example $(x, y) = (19, 93)$ does not appear. To find all the solutions I recommend reading the Wikipedia link shared by Calvin Lin about the multiplicative principle.

I've just seen that I had written "I claim that... is a solution of $(2)$". Clearly, I meant $(1)$. I guess this confused you.

@DavideMasi, you meant (1)? I didn't know that at all.

I fixed that before writing my last comment. You can read my answer again if you wish. I am sure you will understand it :)

No words man, no words. You and @CalvinLin have me shown me a new way of solving pell type equations. I understand your beautiful answer now. Thanks a hell lot for your hardwork and patience.

I really enjoyed writing this answer, I Iearnt many things in the process. Glad to hear that you liked it!

@DavideMasi, thanks again. I really thought I was such a bother asking stupid questions.

Your question made me think a lot, so it was not stupid at all. Keep it up :)

@DavideMasi, thanks for saying that. Best wishes.

[EDIT: This is my first answer. See my new answer]
Everything is correct up to $24x^2 - y^2 = 15$. Then $\color{green}{ \frac{24}{15}x^2−\frac{1}{15}y^2 = 1}$ which has infinitely many solutions. You can check that $(x,y)=(1,3) \implies n=-1 \lor n=-2$ which are not natural numbers, so you should compute other solutions and look for the smallest value of $x$ which works (i. e. provides a value of $n$ which is a natural number).
EDIT: The least working couple is $(x,y) = (19, 93)$, as suggested by @NagaSaiPrajith in their answer.
EDIT (2): As pointed out in the comments, you found one integer solution $(X, y)=(4, 15)$ to $X^2 - \frac{1}{15}y^2=1$. However, you must find integer values of $x$, so I suggest that you do not substitute $X = \frac{24}{15}x $ and find integer solutions to my green equation. By the way, remember that infinitely many solutions exist and there are ways to compute them without computers. However, I guess you must check them by hand at least.

HOW do I compute them without computers? who would've thought about 93 anything?

I mean, after you fix $x$ you have a quadratic equation in $y$ and $x=19$ is relatively small. I'm not sure there is a general formula to find integer solutions to that equation :/

relatively small? I have to check through like (1...19) for just a part of the solution? It's like 1 sum, 1 in 1 exercise of an ELEMEMTARY number theory book. You're right, maybe I'm too stupid for any of this.

You should cool down. I first answered when your question contained many mistakes and then I tried to help writing what I was able to think of. Anyway, never say you are stupid, just relax and take your time to find the solution. You might just not know enough to solve this problem.

@JW Are you familiar with Pell's equation? Once you found the specific solution $(x,y) = (1, 3)$, you can multiply it with the solutions to $y^2 - 24x^2 = 1$ which are of the form $(1, 5)^n$. The idea is that $(a^2 - 24 b^2)(c^2 - 24d^2) = (ac+24bd)^2 - 24(ad+bc)^2$. So for example, $-15 = (3^2 - 24\cdot 1^2)(5^2 - 24\cdot 1^2) = ( 15 + 24)^2 - 24(3+5)^2$. From the theory, $(x, y) = (8, 39)$ is the next smallest solution, not $(19, 93)$.

@CalvinLin thank you very much legend (I guess you meant to address me). I will edit my answer to include your insights. Before I do so, could you clarify what $(1,5)^n$ means here?

@DavideMasi Oh yes, I misread the solution poster due to the formatting. The operation is $(a, b) * (c, d) = (ac + 24 bd, ad + bc)$. For example, $(3, 1) * (5, 1) = ( 15 + 24, 3 + 5)$. From the theory, all solutions are of the form $(3, 1) * (5, 1) * (5, 1) \ldots * (5, 1)$. (The operation is commutative, so order does not matter.)

@CalvinLin great. Could you also provide some references which prove that no other solutions exist? I would love to learn more about it and post them in my answer

Like I said, check out Pell's equation - Solutions to $X^2 - DY^2 = k$. for non-square $D$. If a solution exists, then it has the form that I stated. The difficulty is finding an initial solution (which doesn't necessarily have small values).

@CalvinLin it looks to me that the solution $(19,93)$ does not appear in the sequence. Why is that?

Oh good point. Turns out that the $ k \neq 1$ situation is more complicated than I rememebred. There is a finite (not necessarily just 1 which was my error, bounded in both coordiantes so exhaustive search works) set of starting solutions,  which then generate the infinite family $(X, Y) ( U, V)^n$, which gives us all solutions. In this case,  $ (9, 2)$ is another starting solution with $24 \times 2^2 - 9^2 = 15$, and we can derive $(9, 2) * (5, 1) = (45 + 48, 9 + 10) = (93, 19)$.

@CalvinLin  I put the whole thing as interwoven Fibonacci type sequences, two such sequences are required. I wrote it in terms of the original variable named $n,$   as in $(3n^2 + 9n + 8)/2$  being a square. So that $(93,19)$   for me appears as $(14, 19)$

@CalvinLin I would appreciate if you read my answer :)

Pell type equations can be solved, for each variable, by one or more interwoven general Fibonacci type sequences.  For the number you called  $n,$  the sequence of values I will call $n_j$  begins
$$ -1, 0, 5, 14, 63, 152, 637, 1518, 6319, ...  $$
and obeys a rule involving every second value (note the $n_{j+4}$ and $n_{j+2}$) as
$$ \huge \color{magenta}{ n_{j+4}  = 10 n_{j+2}  - n_j  + 12 }  $$
for example $10 \cdot 5 - (-1) + 12 =  50 + 1 + 12 = 63$    and
$10 \cdot 14 - 0 + 12 = 140 + 12 = 152    $
These $n_j,$  beginning with the $5,$ are the positive values of $n$ for which
$$ \sqrt{ \frac{3n^2 + 9n + 8}{2}  }    $$
is an integer
I guess I should show those integer square roots,
$$ 1, 2, 8, 19, 79, 188, 782, 1861, 7741, ...    $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{c|ccccccc} 
n & -1 & 0 &  5 &14 & 63 & 152 & 637 & 1518 & 6319 \\ 
\sqrt{\frac{3n^2 + 9n + 8}{2}} & 1 & 2 & 8& 19 & 79 & 188& 782 & 1861 & 7741 \\  
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
How to generate all   solutions of $u^2 - 24 v^2 = -15.$ Given a solution $(u,v)$  with $u,v > 0,$  larger  solutions  comes from
$$ (u,v) \mapsto (5u+24v, u+5 v )  $$
This has a nice inverse,
$$ (u,v) \mapsto (5u-24v, -u+5 v ) . $$
Any solution with $u,v > 0$ can be mapped backwards, a descent step, to a fundamental solution,   meaning either $-u+5v \leq 0$ or $5u-24v \leq 0.$  The former condition does not happen, because $u^2 < 24 v^2.$ It is the latter  condition that happens, $5u < 24v.$ The intersection of the line $5u = 24 v$ with the hyperbola $u^2 - 24 v^2 = -15$  is $ (6 \sqrt{10}, \frac{5 \sqrt{10}}{4})  $  or roughly $ 18.97, 3.95.$  Those are the bounds for fundamental solutions, the two  successes are marked with dots, $(3,1)$  and $(9,2)$


Why does a pink equation need to be huge too?  Too much emphasis is distracting.

Great answer. But I didn't get the bounds part. And the successes? Forgive my ignorance, will really appreciate if you can clarify what you mean by those.

The pair $(x,y) = (19,93) $ satisfies your equation $24x^2-y^2 = 15$ and it can be verified that this is the least solution which gives a positive value of $n$ by a simple program.

19,93 are quite large numbers. I corrected the question now.

@xoco I suggest that you read my answer entirely :)
